# Finding the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I've come across the following integration problem online:

$$\int{\frac{x^3}{x^4-2x+1}}\,\,dx$$

This is beyond my current knowledge of integrals, but it seems to be a very interesting integration problem.  Would anyone be able to give a tip on how to being solving the expression?

If there are any techniques, please elucidate - i.e. substitution, trigonometric identities, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a nice answer to this: you have to factor the denominator and use partial fractions, and the roots are nasty.

Comment: Let me WA it for you: ([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x^3%2F%28x^4-2x%2B1%29+dx))

Comment: @mvw already done that, the answer scared me!

Comment: If you factor the denominator you get $(x-1) (x^3+x^2+x-1)$ the first factor gives the logarithm summand, the second that nasty other summand.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:You can solve the intgral in this way:
$$\int{\frac{x^3}{x^4-2x+1}}\,\,dx=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\int{\frac{4x^3+2-2}{x^4-2x+1}}\,\,dx=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\int{\frac{4x^3-2}{x^4-2x+1}}\,\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\int{\frac{2}{x^4-2x+1}}\,\,dx=$$
$$\frac{1}{4}ln|x^4-2x+1|+\frac{1}{4}\int{\frac{2}{x^4-2x+1}}\,\,dx=$$
and then you have to factor the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

You would start by factoring the denominator as $(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x-1)$ and then writing 
$$
\frac{x^3}{x^4-2x+1} = \frac12 \left[ \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{x^2-1}{x^3+x^2+x-1}\right]
$$
The first term is easy to integrate.  The second term can be integrated by factoring the denominator and doing a similar trick; unfortunately, the expressin is an ugly mess involving things like 
$$\sqrt[3]{17 + 3\sqrt{33}}$$
so the closed form integral must be pretty ugly.